# How do you create a slice of ocean with an animated surface in blender 2.8?

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to do this...

[image]

... as featured in [this post](https://blenderartists.org/t/slice-of-water/565839/2), but in blender 2.8.

The only way that I can get anywhere close is to create an ocean slightly larger in X & Y than the cube, but shorter in Z. Then add a boolean on the cube with the object as the ocean and the operation set to difference. However, I can then only remove the faces of the cube above the ocean once the boolean modifier is applied, which means that the animation won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Simon

EDIT: Having downloaded blender 2.79 and added a boolean intersect to the cube I get similar behaviour to blender 2.8 when the solver is set to BMesh...

[image]

...but setting the solver to Carve gives me the desired result.

[image]

So it looks as if blender 2.8 (which has removed the solver Carve) cannot generate the desired result.

So the questions stands, how do you create a slice of ocean with an animated surface in blender 2.8?

Thanks (again),

Simon

Comment: Don't apply modifier, just hide Cube from viewport and rendering - settings are in Outliner.

Comment: Thanks Serge L. However, I want the sides of the cube visible to give the appearance of a slice or cross section of ocean

Comment: does it need to be the Ocean modifier? Because you could fake it with the Displacement modifier or other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a Plane and subdivide it couple of times
2. Select its border and add it to a new vertex group

   [image]
3. Add all modifiers to the stack, pay attention to green highligts

   [image]

Ocean should be *Displace* instead of *Generate* in order to utilize vertex group.

Vertex group later is displaced strictly on Z axis down below and cut by Cube via boolean *Intersect*.

Adjust Cube's scale as you need and enable Autosmooth (80 deg) in Plane settings to have a sharp corner at the cut.

[image]

Comment: Following your instructions I cannot generate the output required. One missing element was to set the Displace modifier strength to -20, but even then I cannot replicate what you have done. I think the issue might be in selecting the border of the plane and adding it to the vector group. However, since you have provided a .blend file I can use that. Many Thanks